# mex + nvcc linker problems with standard library

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc, cuda

I'm having some trouble getting Matlab mex to link to the C++ standard library on Mac OS X Maverics. The problem occurs when linking to code generated by nvcc.

All errors are related to the standard library:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
  ...`

As far as I can tell both nvcc and mex are using the same compiler (gcc -> clang) and they both link to `-lstdc++/-stdlib=libstdc++`, yet it still results in a whole bunch of linker errors. If I on the other hand compile the offending instruction:

`gcc -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map -o  "solver_matlab.mexmaci64"  solver_matlab.o  "../solver_cu.o"  "../solver_cu_link.o"  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcudart -lcublas -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++`

using `gcc-4.8` in terminal, then the code compiles correctly. I'm not sure how to make heads or tails of the issue, so I'd be very thankful if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon the same problem, the solution turned out to be to pass the two additional flags to mex

`LDFLAGS='\$LDFLAGS -stdlib=libstdc++' CXXFLAGS='\$CXXFLAGS -stdlib=libstdc++'`